# Can't create databases with names starting with 4E followed by alternate digits and letters.

Tags: mysql, database

I have this (probably stupid) question about MySQL database names.

Why this statement: "CREATE DATABASE 4E2A_TEST_DB;" throws this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

While just adding another letter after "4E" (e.g. "CREATE DATABASE 4EX2A_TEST_DB;") works as expected and creates the database?

I tried finding more details in MySQL's documentation but there was nothing specific there...